# Cholesky Decomposition in OpenCV

Tags: c++, opencv, linear-algebra

I'm trying to get the Cholesky decomposition of a matrix and am having trouble understanding why the result is not working. I've tried using just the 3x3 identity matrix and using a 2x2 matrix I can get the decomposition for in matlab.

I reference the docs here

https://docs.opencv.org/master/d8/d0e/group__core__hal__interface__decomp__cholesky.html

Although in my version the bool is the return value (not passed in by reference).

Any ideas why this would be failing? I expected this to be trivial since I'm solving Ax=B where A and B are the identity matrix (or the example 2x2) and that the data in `mat` after would be either the identity matrix or `[0.4538, 0; 0.0004, 0.4834]` for the 2x2.

Code is

```
#include <iostream>
#include "opencv2/core/core.hpp"
#include "opencv2/core/operations.hpp"

int main()
{
//    int rows = 2;
//    float data[4] = {0.2059, 0.0002, 0.0002, 0.2336};
//    cv::Mat mat = cv::Mat(rows, rows, CV_32F, data);
    int rows = 3;
    cv::Mat mat = cv::Mat::eye(rows, rows, CV_32F);
    std::cout << "Have mat\n" << mat << std::endl;
    std::size_t bytes_per_row = sizeof(float)*rows;
    cv::Mat mat2 = mat.clone();
    bool result = cv::Cholesky(reinterpret_cast<float *>(&mat), bytes_per_row, rows, reinterpret_cast<float *>(&mat2), bytes_per_row, rows);
    std::cout << "Did we succeed?\n" << result << std::endl;
    std::cout << "After\n" << mat << std::endl;
}
```

compiled on my machine using

``` g++ -std=c++11 test.cpp -o main `pkg-config opencv --cflags --libs````

**Edit**

After the comment from Frank I changed how the matrices were passed in. The function now returns true but does not return the result I expect. Based on the documentation the first matrix passed in should now point to the decomposition and while it has changed it is not lower triangular and multiplying it by it's transpose does not return the original matrix. I am able to isolate this by passing in a `nullptr` as the second matrix (per the documentation). So the following code

```
#include <iostream>
#include "opencv2/core/core.hpp"
#include "opencv2/core/operations.hpp"

int main()
{
    int rows = 2;
    float data[4] = {9, 2, 2, 8};
    cv::Mat mat = cv::Mat(rows, rows, CV_32F, data);
    std::size_t bytes_per_row = sizeof(float)*rows;
    std::cout << "Before 1\n" << mat << std::endl;
    bool result = cv::Cholesky(mat.ptr<float>(), bytes_per_row, rows, nullptr, bytes_per_row, rows);
    std::cout << "Did we succeed?\n" << result << std::endl;
    std::cout << "After 1\n" << mat << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Does it match?\n" << mat*mat.t() << std::endl;
}
```

Now yields...

```
Before 1
[9, 2;
  2, 8]
Did we succeed?
1
After 1
[0.33333334, 2;
  0.66666669, 0.36380345]
Does it match?
[4.1111112, 0.9498291;
  0.9498291, 0.57679743]
```

The expected solution would be

```
3.0000         0
    0.6667    2.7487
```

Which is lower triangular and meets the requirements for the decomposition.

Per another comment I will also submit a request to the open CV github.

Comment: `reinterpret_cast<float *>(&mat)` is absolutely illegal. I can't say for 100% sure this will make things for you, but you "probably" want `mat.ptr<float>()` instead.

Comment: you might want to submit an issue on opencv's github and request a *proper* Cholesky API that takes Mat instead of pointers. this API is very ugly.